# How to stop a service from BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a BroadcastReceiver which receives a JSON of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) upon passing a parameter, according to which a service is beginning a global object of the class, the service sends the location of the cell to a server every so often, then sent him another message on the same GCM to stop him, the problem is that when I stop the service says this service is NULL, but still sends the location. I want to stop the service to stop sending the location.

`BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

String TAG = "MainActivity";
ServicioGPS service1;
int nroService;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // == I get the JSON
    Bundle extras= intent.getExtras();
    // == I check if I want to start the service
    if (extras.containsKey("Position")) {
        service1 = new ServiceGPS(context);
        nroService= service1.onStartCommand(intent, 0, 58);
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(nroService));
    }
    else
    {
        // == I check if I want to stop the service
        if (extras.containsKey("stop")) {
            // == Exist error in this line(service1 is NULL)
            service1.stopSelf();
            // == Exist error in this line (service1 is NULL)
        }
        else
        {
            // == I Make a notification
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());              
            Log.i(TAG, "Entro al else del broadcast");
            // Starts the service, keeping the device awake.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }

}
```

}

List of errors

```
07-31 19:26:44.115: D/AndroidRuntime(3292): Shutting down VM
07-31 19:26:44.115: W/dalvikvm(3292): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception             (group=0x41ce0700)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  receiver com.ubaldino.demo_gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2541)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at com.ubaldino.demo_gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:34)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2525)
07-31 19:26:44.120: E/AndroidRuntime(3292):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never directly call onDestroy or any other lifecycle function.  To stop a service, use `context.stopService()`

Also to start a service, you use context.startService().  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it won't really start the service and will cause problems with the framework if it doesn't just crash.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was wrong to put the OnDestroy(), also tried the stopSelf() and nothing, the service still NULL.

Comment: Because you aren't starting it right either.  You need to start it via startService.  You never directly create a service or activity

Answer (score 1):

***You can access the service at any time because the service is registered in the system ("Thread") wait to be activated or stops at any time.***

**Example:**

```
      public class Phonecall extends BroadcastReceiver {

         @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent song_wweather=  new Intent(context,Song_weather.class); //service class
            if(intent.getAction()=="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"){

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
    (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

         PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
              {
           if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                context.stopService(song_wweather);
           }


               if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
        context.startService(song_wweather);
                 }
                 }
             };
      telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

     }}
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

What @GabeSechan is mentioning about stopping your service is right.

But conceptual looking at your code it does seem like you think that from one onReceive callback to the next that your ServicioGPS service1 instance will still be available.  It will not and that's why you're getting a `NullPointerException`.  It's important to understand that when a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method finishes it is destroyed.  Here's some info on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle), it should help you understand.

Looks like you're dealing with 2 services in this BroadcastReceiver.  You need to use `context.startService() and context.stopService` as mentioned by @GabeSechan or `startWakefulService` if you want to start a service with a wake lock.  Never create or destroy your services manually.

I hope this clears up your understanding a bit.